# How to get old text and changed text of textbox on TextChanged event of textbox?

Tags: c#, .net

I am fairly new to c#. I have requirement of previous text and newly changed text of text box on text changed event of the same. I tried to get text on textchanged event but it is new text only. How can I get previous text also?

e.g. Say I have  a text "abc" in my text box and I change it to "pqr" by pasting  text directly and not by typing. now on text change event txtbox.text returns me  "pqr" .
But I need to compare previous and new text , so I need "abc" also. So how can I get it?

```
private void txtFinalTrans_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gstrOldText = txtFinalTrans.Text;              
}
```

Comment: oldTextCount = newChangesCount - 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try creating a global variable and put your textbox text during `GotFocus` event and use it as Old Text during `TextChanged` event as like:

```
string OldText = string.Empty;
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OldText = textBox1.Text;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string newText = textBox1.Text;
   //Compare OldText and newText here
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Why not use the Enter event, it fires before GotFocus? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the old value. For example in a field or property in the same class.

```
private string LastFinalTrans { get; set; }

private void txtFinalTrans_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;
    if(LastFinalTrans == txt.Text)
    {
        // ...
    }
    LastFinalTrans =  txt.Text;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works! The sender always contains the changed text.

Answer (score 2):

Declare  OldValue  String in Public

```
private void textbox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
            {
                OldValue = textbox1.Text.Trim();
            }

        }
```

In Leave funcation...

```
private void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Newvalue = textbox1.Text;
            //Compare Both Values 

            //OldValue and Newvalue
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hail,

In the case of ASP.NET, the easiest way to accomplish this feat is to use a hiddenField. At one point I hoped I could just have added a data property on the textbox and place the old value there with a touch of JavaScript, then read that attribute in the code behind. But unfortunately, that's not the way the postback system works.

So, we want to grab the old value and save it in a hidden field as soon as the user places the cursor in the TextBox. We accomplish this by setting onfocus property of the TextBox to the name of the javascript method what will do the saving. Let's call this method saveOldValue.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   onfocus="setOldValue()" OnTextChanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="oldValueHiddenField" Value="" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Before adding the javascript setOldValue method: To make the code as generic as possible, let's not make the saveOldValue method know anything about the specific TextBox that called it or the specific HiddenField it will save the old value to. That way we can use this method with any TextBox and HiddenFields. So let's pass saveOldValue the current instance of the textbox, so it can access the properties of the TextBox. Also, let's add a property on the TextBox that will hold the ID of the hiddenField that will eventually store the old Value; let's call this property data-hiddenField and assign it the ID of the HiddenField.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  data-hiddenField="oldValueHiddenField" onfocus="setOldValue(this)" OnTextChanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="oldValueHiddenField" Value="" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Next, let's set up the method setOldVaue in JavaScript:

```
<script>

function setOldValue(e){
//I am using a bit of jQuery here, but feel free to go pure JS

        var hiddenField = $(e).attr("data-hiddenField");
        var oldValue = $(e).val();

        $("#"+hiddenField).val(oldValue);

}

</script>
```

Next, Let's get the values in the code behind on the TextChanged event [fires when you leave the textbox]:

```
protected void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    var oldVaue = oldValueHiddenField.Value;
    var newValue = tb.Text;
}
```

Hope this added some value.

//Peace