# get deleted text from wpf textbox in TextChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to get text that is removed from WPF TextBox in `TextChanged` event?

this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311082/how-to-get-old-text-and-changed-text-of-textbox-on-textchanged-event-of-textbox) which is about Windows forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get old text and changed text of textbox on TextChanged event of textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311082/how-to-get-old-text-and-changed-text-of-textbox-on-textchanged-event-of-textbox)

Comment: @MikeEason it`s not duplicate of what you have mentioned.

Comment: You can always save all history of text in string collection.

Comment: @SHM the same solution would work though.

Comment: You could create a derived TextBox and register a PropertyChangedCallback for the Text property by OverrideMetadata.

Comment: @ChrisF GotFocus is invoked just once thus it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one global variable. And assign old value to it on `KeyDown` event and use this in `TextChanged` event:

```
    string oldText;
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        oldText = tb.Text;
    }  

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(oldText);
    }
```

Comment: this will not work, because the user might select some text and delete them at once.