# Updating primary key value in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a form that updates the SQL database with content written in it.
ClientCode is a primary key.
My update query is the following:

```
string query = $@"UPDATE {clientTableName}
                                SET ClientCode = @clientCode,
                                    CompanyName = @companyName,
                                    Address1 = @address1,
                                    Address2 = @address2,
                                    City = @city,
                                    Province = @province,
                                    PostalCode = @postalCode,
                                    YTDSales = @ytdSales,
                                    CreditHold = @creditHold,
                                    Notes = @notes
                                WHERE ClientCode = @clientCode";
```

Problem with this query is it will select the new clientCode in the where cause, meaning that the query will not be able to select the correct primary key.

For example, if I type "BOTTN", the query will look for "BOTTN" instead of "BOTTM" in the where cause.

How I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: You need to keep the previous value for your primary key and pass it in another parameter and use that parameter for the WHERE condition while the new value is used for the SET assignment

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: When you load your form with the current data save the value of the current primary key somewhere in your form global level variables. Then when you save the data create a separate parameter for this 'current' value and modify the query

Comment: To write a full answer I need to see how you have loaded the form with the database data

Comment: Submit the current clientCode as a hidden or readonly field or similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get old text and changed text of textbox on TextChanged event of textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311082/how-to-get-old-text-and-changed-text-of-textbox-on-textchanged-event-of-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the old clientCode and the new clientCode. The `WHERE` clause needs to contain the old clientCode in order to target the existing row in the database. Then you can update the row, including the value for the new clientCode.

```
string query = $@"UPDATE {clientTableName}
                            SET ClientCode = @newClientCode,     -- NEW
                                CompanyName = @companyName,
                                Address1 = @address1,
                                Address2 = @address2,
                                City = @city,
                                Province = @province,
                                PostalCode = @postalCode,
                                YTDSales = @ytdSales,
                                CreditHold = @creditHold,
                                Notes = @notes
                            WHERE ClientCode = @oldClientCode";  -- OLD
```

Get the new client code from the text box in your `EditDialog` and save the old client code as a member variable or something when you retrieve the row from the database in order to display the individual fields in the `EditDialog`.

Comment: Sometimes the primary key does need to be updated, yes. Although arguably there are more sophisticated ways to design a database than this (using surrogate keys, uniqueness constraints, etc). But unless the solution is intended to be enterprise-grade, in this case I wouldn't worry about it.